# Correct way to analyze paths from $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Tags: php

I am trying to write a small RESTful Service API in PHP5.4 (for educational purpose). Therefor I need to analyze the URL with which the service is called.

The way I want to do this is to strip down the URL paths from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and put them to an array. Let's assume the path info contains `/contacts/14295/`. What is the right way to put the two paths to an array like following?

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(8) "contacts"
 [1]=>
 string(5) "14295"
}
```

I found at least two ways to split the path info string to an array but both ways result in an array with more then two entries.

The first way I found is the [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) function which returns an array with trailing empty strings (means the first and last array entry contain an empty string):

```
explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Then I tried the preg_split function which returns an array that contains an entry for every slash ('/'):

```
preg_split('//', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Both variants are it very unhandy for me to get the paths from URL. I would wonder if there is not a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim the "/" from the start and end of the array?

```
$array = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/') );
```